# Is it possible to send images through Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

Title. I am trying to figure out if its even possible to send images through Amazon SNS. What I've found so far seems to indicate that its not but I was hoping to get a concrete answer.

Comment: A common method is to store images in Amazon S3 and then send a reference to the image via Amazon SNS. What is your use-case? Feel free to edit your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the size of your images.

If you're using a SDK that supports AWS Signature version 4, the raw message limit is 256KB.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/large-payload-raw-message.html

Comment: Thank you I'll look into this

Comment: this is wrong. SNS only supports text. You can send text of an S3 image URL

Comment: You can base64 encode a binary file before sending it, so you can indeed send the content of the image

Comment: will try this out.

Comment: So I tried it out and got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sns-raw.py", line 8, in <module>
    AttributeValue='true'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 276, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
 ...
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the SetSubscriptionAttributes operation: Invalid parameter: Delivery protocol [sms] does not support raw message delivery.

Comment: python3 sns-raw.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sns-raw.py", line 11, in <module>
    AttributeValue='true'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 276, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
....
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the SetSubscriptionAttributes operation: Invalid parameter: Delivery protocol [email] does not support raw message delivery.

Comment: "Raw message delivery support is supported with SQS and HTTP(S) endpoints. Deliveries to Lambda, email, and SMS endpoints will behave the same independent of the “RawMessageDelivery” property.". FYI You may have more luck creating your own question for your specific needs as it does not seem to align with this one.