# AWS SNS Mobile Push Notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

We have a requirement to have a durable mobile push notification; and we found AWS SNS with AWS cognito. Our big concern is that we found out that AWS SNS aren't supporting Image or blob data type unlike onesignal.

Is there any way that AWS SNS can support image in push mobile notification (the image will show also in notif preview)

Answer (score 0):

[Is it possible to send images through Amazon SNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505702/is-it-possible-to-send-images-through-amazon-sns)

According to this answer, is not possible, unless you base64 encode a binary file before sending it, then you could send the content of an image.